# Unix Shell scripting for copying file from one folder to another

Tags: shell, unix

Hi this is my shell script to copy files from one directory to another  directory with timestamp.But my script shows too many arguments.I want to copy files from one directory to another.What error in my code.

```
Date_Val="$(date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S)";

cd /etl_mbl/SrcFiles/

if [  -f /etl_mbl/SrcFiles/SrcFiles_TEMP*.csv ]
then
cp /etl_mbl/SrcFiles/SrcFiles_TEMP/*.csv /etl_mbl/SrcFiles/Archive/*_$Date_Val.csv
fi
```

Comment: You want the file name appended with the timestamp in the new location?

Answer (score 2):

The reason you got "too many arguments" error is that the wildcard in the "if" statement expands to a multitude of files. Please also note that you cannot have wildcards in the destination of a "cp". You probably want something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

Date_Val="$(date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S)";

for file in ./src/*.csv; do
    filename=${file##*/}
    basename=${filename%.*}
    cp $file ./archive/$basename\_$Date_Val.csv
done
```

Comment: What's with the `./` obsession? Is it good for anything in this case? It's also a good idea to quote $file and the destination file name to avoid word-splitting and glob expansion.

Comment: No, the ./ is not necessary. It should be noted that the original post uses absolute paths that probably are invalid on most systems.